# Как в Lua можно в текстовой строке заменить каждый "\" на "\\"?

Tags: lua

Каким образом в Lua можно во всей строке заменить каждый "`\`" на "`\\`"?

Из строки:

```
Какой результат он вернет?\par\mintinline{postgresql}{SELECT 3/2;}
```

получить строку:

```
Какой результат он вернет?\\par\\mintinline{postgresql}{SELECT 3/2;}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно например используя [string.gsub](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html)

```
print ("?\\par\\mintinline{postgresql}{SELECT 3/2;}")
print (string.gsub("?\\par\\mintinline{postgresql}{SELECT 3/2;}", "\\", "\\\\"))
```